# replaceAll not working for '(' or ')'

Tags: apex, string

I am trying to parse a string and want to replace All '(' with ' ( ' when I try to execute the following command

```
String s1 = '1AND( 2  OR  3  )  AND4 AND(5OR6)';
s1=s1.replaceAll( '(' , ' ( ' );
```

I get the following error

```
FATAL_ERROR System.StringException: Invalid regex: Unclosed group near index 1
```

When I try to use replace instead of replaceAll it works But I want to use replace all, please suggest me how to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to update your replacement string to use an escape against "(" since these are special characters in regex.

Try the following:

```
String s1 = '1AND( 2  OR  3  )  AND4 AND(5OR6)';
s1=s1.replaceAll( '\\(' , ' ( ' );
```

It is worth reading the [Salesforce documentation for String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) to understand the difference between replace and replaceAll. For literal replacements such as this one you probably can use String.replace.